# Compile a LambdaExpression with additional parameter

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

I am trying to get a MethodInfo object and call Invoke() on it. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
public class ContactCustomFieldsFacet
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> Fields { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, string>();

}

public static class FacetExtensions
{
    public static Func<ContactCustomFieldsFacet, object> Compile(string body)
    {
        ParameterExpression prm = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ContactCustomFieldsFacet), typeof(ContactCustomFieldsFacet).Name);
        LambdaExpression exp = DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda(new[] { prm }, typeof(object), body);
        return (Func<ContactCustomFieldsFacet, object>)exp.Compile();
    }
}

var lambda = FacetExtensions.Compile($"ContactCustomFieldsFacet.Fields[\"test\"]");
var propertyMethod = lambda.Method;
// No control over the below code - it's called by a third party library
ContactCustomFieldsFacet facet = GetFacet();
propertyMethod.Invoke(null, new [] { facet }); // System.ArgumentException: MethodInfo must be a runtime MethodInfo object.
```

Essentially I want to be able to dynamically create an expression that has the `ContactCustomFieldsFacet.Fields` dictionary index field hardcoded for that instance.
I realise I might be on the wrong track so any pointers would be appreciated.

.NET Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ecMRye

**EDIT**

Thanks to Corey I've updated the code but am still getting a similar issue

.NET Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5hDOsd

Comment: How certain are you about the `null` object parameter in the invoke?  If it actually does `func.Method.Invoke(func.Target, ...)` then there's a simple way to do it.  Anything that uses `DynamicMethod` or similar (including LINQ Expressions and direct emits) will fail on this step.

Answer (score 2):

Locating the method you want to call is reasonably simple reflection.  The hard part is figuring out the name of the method to call.  Sometimes the simplest thing to do is to create an expression and have a look at how the Compiler put it together.

For instance, this:

```
Expression<Func<Dictionary<string, string>, string>> expr = d => d["test"];
```

If you inspect (or `Dump()`, if you're using LINQPad) the `expr` variable you'll be able to wander through the generated expression tree and look at things like the method information in the `Call` node.

In your case it seems that you want to invoke `get_Item` on the `Dictionary<string, string>` class.  It requires an object reference and a string parameter for the key.  Object instance will be the `Fields` property value from the supplied `ContactCustomFieldsFacet` so we'll need to grab that.

Building the whole thing by hand might look something like this:

```
public static Func<ContactCustomFieldsFacet, string> MakeAccessor(string key)
{
    var tFacet = typeof(ContactCustomFieldsFacet);
    var piFields = tFacet.GetProperty("Fields");
    var miFieldsGet = piFields.PropertyType.GetMethod("get_Item");

    var param = Expression.Parameter(tFacet, "facet");
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<ContactCustomFieldsFacet, object>>
    (
        Expression.Call
        (
            // Instance for invocation: param.Fields
            Expression.MakeMemberAccess(param, piFields),
            // Method to call
            miFieldsGet,
            // Call arguments
            Expresion.Constant(key)
        ),
        param
    );

    return lambda.Compile();
}
```

Invoking that method will get you a `Func<>` that returns the value for a specific `key`, as set at the time the `Func<>` was built.  For instance:

```
var fnGetTest = MakeAccessor("test");
var value = fnGetTest(someFacetInstance);
```

This all assumes that the dictionary stores reference types - string works fine.  If it's a value type (int for example) you'll need to box the value by `Convert`ing to `object`.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful answer. Unfortunately I can't just call `fnGetTest(someFacetInstance)` directly as I need to pass it through to a third party DLL to invoke. Any ideas? Question updated.

Comment: Ah, I missed that the 3rd-party library was trying to `Invoke` the `Method`.  `Lambda.Compile` returns a delegate that can't be used this way.  You're probably going to be stuck with classic runtime emits *(shudder)* to get this.  Or Roslyn maybe.  To be clear, `func(...)` and `func.Invoke(...)` work, `func.Method.Invoke(...)` doesn't.